# How to get k min element's original index

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have an array like {40,78,56,98,1,-9} and this array's size can be huge. I want to get the first K min element's index. I can use min-heap/ priority-queue to get K min elements in very good time complexity. But I don't know how can I get their index. Please guide me in some ways I can solve my issue.

I have tried using TreeMap to get same but that is taking too much time if array grows bigger.

Example 
input : {40,78,56,98,1,-9}, K = 2
output : {5,4}

Comment: How did you get {3,1} in your example?

Comment: @NestorSokil sorry i am stupid , Now it is correct

Comment: Take a look at mine answer and see if it suits you. @ManishSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to use a Priority Queue you can add the value as well as index in the priority queue by making a class Pair and passing a comparator while intializing the priority queue.
The Pair class can be as follows:

```
class Pair {
    Pair(int val, int idx){
        this.val = val;
        this.idx = idx;
    }
    int val;
    int idx;
}
```

1. You can create a max heap and add first **k** elements in to it.
2. Traverse the array from **(k + 1)th** element.
3. Check if the max element(i.e. is the root of the heap) is less than the **(k + 1)th** element, if it is less, than remove max element and add the new element to the heap creating a new Pair object.
4. Perform **Step 3** till you reach the end of the array.

You can initialize the priority queue as below:

```
Queue<Pair> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(k, (pair1, pair2) -> -Integer.compare(pair1.val, pair2.val));
```

Comment: I want to learn those lambda and functional programming, what acc to you , should be my initial path..

Comment: Above method is all about comparing two objects, you could have written an anonymous class Comparator or you could have implemented Comparable interface in Pair class, nothing to do with functional programming in that case. And  about lambdas you will get used to, if you try to use them and bring them to your practice. There are various sources for learning and reading about the same. You can easily find them through google.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I assume you want something like following: Get indexes of first 2 min elements of the given array. It could be achieved like following:

```
 int[] array = {5,75,73,4,78,6,4,3,4,3,64};
 // stream the array of integers, box them, sort them by comparing values of their indexes, unbox them, limit only first 2 and get them to array.
 int[] getIndexes = IntStream.range(0, array.length).boxed().sorted(Comparator.comparing(i -> array[i])).mapToInt(i->i).limit(2).toArray();
```